# Same DNS server for many different Tor 'idenitities'

Tags: linux, dns, server, ip-address, identity-change

In my browser ([Iceweasel](https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel)), which is running with Tor via [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/), I changed my IP address a good few times, by restarting Tor. Each time, I did the standard test at [dnsleaktest.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) and, the result was the exact same DNS server from level 3 communications, over and over. Is this normal? I would have thought that perhaps the DNS server would change with each new 'identity'.

A little extra info:

- I did this on a Debian Linux.
- Iceweasel is, I believe, very very similar to Firefox, being a fork of Firefox, and is basically the same thing where this issue is concerned.
- I am using the default setting of proxychains, which is to just use Tor.
- I restarted Tor using `service tor restart`.

Comment: Do you use the Tor Browser or have you individually configured a browser?

Comment: Yes, I should really have provided a little more detail, I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxychains uses a hard-coded DNS resolver. It used to be 4.2.2.2, but I think it's been updated since.

https://github.com/haad/proxychains/blob/master/src/proxyresolv

Comment: Well, that certainly sounds like the answer to my question. The ip in the source there, does not resolve to the level 3 communications server I was finding, but 4.2.2.2 is level 3. Thanks!